# How to use Custom Field to display product brief description in shop page with Woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I was able to add part of the in product description with this code:

```
function get_ecommerce_excerpt(){
    $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
    $excerpt = preg_replace(" ([.*?])",'',$excerpt);
    $excerpt = strip_shortcodes($excerpt);
    $excerpt = strip_tags($excerpt);
    $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, 100);
    $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, strripos($excerpt, " "));
    $excerpt = trim(preg_replace( '/s+/', ' ', $excerpt));
    return $excerpt;
}
```

The problem is that that's not what I'm actually trying to do.

What I'm trying to do is use a custom field area named Brief Description to add 2 lines of whatever text I write inside the field.

Is there a code that I can't use to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The brief description of a WooCommerce product is store as post_excerpt, to programmatically add some text, you need to hook through product excerpt.

```
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'custom_excerpt');

function exc($custom_excerpt) {
    global $post;

    if($post->post_type == 'product'){
        $custom_add = __('This product is unavailable for some countries, please, read our terms & conditions to know more about this.', 'folkstone');

        return $excerpt . $custom_add;
    }else{
        return $excerpt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, @Benoti.

Your code goes into the functions.php file? 

When I tried using it, the shop/category page didn't have any of the description. Created custom fields known as **product** and **custom_add** and added dummy text to see if it would work. But still the same

Comment: Yes in functions.php

Comment: Alright. Now I can see the **This product is unavailable for some countries, please, read our terms & conditions to know more about this**

How can I change that line with a custom field area? Maybe add $brief-descr in the sentence?

Answer (score 0):

Benoti.

I was able to solve the problem that I had with this code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'lk_woocommerce_product_excerpt', 35, 2);
if (!function_exists('lk_woocommerce_product_excerpt')) {
    function lk_woocommerce_product_excerpt()
    {
        $content_length = 10;
        global $post;
        $content = $post->brief_description;
        $wordarray = explode(' ', $content, $content_length + 1);
        if (count($wordarray) > $content_length) :
            array_pop($wordarray);
            array_push($wordarray, '...');
            $content = implode(' ', $wordarray);
            $content = force_balance_tags($content);
        endif;
        echo "<span class='excerpt'><p>$content</p></span>";
    }
}
```

Thanks for taking your time and try helping me.